# Download and Preview a PDF Attachment on vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to add "Download" and "Preview" buttons on vf page with the pdf content uploaded to Attachments.

**Errors:**

1. How to preview the attachment on same tab for a Preview button on vf page.
2. Invalid parameter for function URLFOR
   Error is in expression '{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachmentId)}' in component

**VF Page:**

```
<a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachmentId)}" class="btn btn-info">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span> Download
 </a>
```

**Controller:**

```
Public class AttachmentId{
 public string attachmentid {get; set;}

 public AttachmentId(){
 attachmentid='0018000001AcqAX';
   }
 }
```

Comment: can you clarify, when you say 'tha same tab'... did you try to preview the attachment using Modal/Vustom VF pop-up..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please incorporate following changes:

> Visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="AttachmentClass">
<a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachmentId)}" class="btn btn-info">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span> Download </a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" onclick="return window.open('{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachmentId)}','_top');">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span> Preview</a>
```

> Apex class

```
public class AttachmentClass{
public string attachmentid {get; set;}
public AttachmentClass(){
  attachmentid='0018000001AcqAX';
}
}
```

I think, your class name and variable name are same, that's the reason behind the error.

Comment: No luck still error exists: invalid parameter for function URLFOR
Error is in expression '{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachmentId)}' in component <apex:form>

Answer (score 1):

aha, the example Id used by you belongs to account (key prefix 001). try using a attachment or doc id

Comment: yep ur right. I got the issue just now.